# How to choose the last member of an array in a datalayer?

Tags: google-tag-manager, data-layers

Then I would like to get the smallest child Category of a post that belongs lots of categories (via the datalayer pageCategory used plugin called GTM4WP by Duracell Tomi).

How can I do that?

- I had already known to get the biggest category: pageCategory.1
- Already tried pageCategory.10 or pageCategory.length-1 but didn't work. I'm not really familiar with Javascript. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the length of the array, but with a different syntax:

```
pageCategory[pageCategory.length-1]
```